# AVPlayer freezing issues with iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, avplayer

I have an app that makes extensive use of AVPlayer's setRate:time:atHostTime: method to sync video to audio playing independently in my application.  This has worked great for iOS 6.0, but for some reason making many calls to this method occasionally causes the video to freeze in iOS 7.  Is this a bug?  Has anyone else had this problem?  Also, using the old AVPlayer method seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter exhibits the same issue.